# Why Python isn't loading the ca certificate?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, cacerts

I've added a bundle certificate to python default file

```
>>> import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile='/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem', capath='/usr/lib/ssl/certs', openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/usr/lib/ssl/certs')
```

and the certificate seems to work nicely

```
>>> import requests; requests.get('https://westeurope.experiments.azureml.net', verify='/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem')
<Response [530]>
```

However, when I try to perform the same request without explicitly specifying the certificate file, it fails.

```
>>> requests.get('https://westeurope.experiments.azureml.net')
# ...
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='westeurope.experiments.azureml.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1051)')))
```

In my understanding this shouldn't happen, right? Why isn't Python not loading the certificate I provided in the default path?

I'm using Python 3.7.1

Thanks

Comment: The certificates used by `requests` are not necessarily the ones used by default in `ssl`.  See https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification for where `requests` looks for certificates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`requests` does not use the defaults from `ssl`; it uses envvar `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` or `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` if set and otherwise [uses](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ca-certificates) the (spunoff) [`certifi` module](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/) which depending on how you installed requests&certifi which you didn't say and your environment which you didn't identify might use a system default (which might or might not be the same as the OpenSSL used in `ssl`) or might be its own copy of Mozilla. In the latter case it *should* include Digicert Global Root CA as needed for that site, because Firefox (also Mozilla) does.

Look at `requests.certs.where()` or `python -m requests.certs`

Mostly dupe
[Python Requests - How to use system ca-certificates (debian/ubuntu)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982143/python-requests-how-to-use-system-ca-certificates-debian-ubuntu)
[How to force requests use the certificates on my ubuntu system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448854/how-to-force-requests-use-the-certificates-on-my-ubuntu-system)
[Why python requests not use the system ssl cert by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66848351/why-python-requests-not-use-the-system-ssl-cert-by-default)